# How I can load p: selectOneMenu after uploaded a file with fileUpload?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, jsf-2.2

I am using the fileUpload feature of PrimeFaces 4.0 to upload a .css file. The application then needs to load all of the stylesheet classes in the file. The application then should render a `selectOneMenu` with the classes, one of which the user will choose, which will then apply to another element.

The problem is that I could not find a way to update the `selectOneMenu` after having uploaded a file. I have the file upload even longer as loading the elements from `selectOneMenu` ManageBean.

Here is `upload.xhtml`:

```
<h:form id="Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{sintaxisWizard.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced" 
    update="growl productCode" 
    label="Escoge archivo css" 
    auto="true"
    sizeLimit="10485760" 
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(css)$/" 
    invalidSizeMessage="El maximo tamaño del archivo es 10 Megabytes !"
    invalidFileMessage="Unicamente se puede subir archivos css" />
</h:form>
```

And my `selectOneMenu`

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="combo" value="#{sintaxisWizard.animalSelected}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..."  noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{sintaxisWizard.allAnimals}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Si lees una sola cosa en esta página, lee esto: favor de no usar el Traductor Google para traducir del español al inglés. No funciona bien. If you read one thing on this page, please read this: please don't use Google Translate from Spanish into English. It doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

*Si necesitas una traducción al español, y te lo proveeré.*

You will need to set the `update` component of your `p:fileUpload` to actually update the correct component. Right now, it is set to update `growl` and `productCode`, but not `combo`, the ID of your `p:selectOneMenu`.

None of this deals with the problems you will face in dynamically loading a new CSS page for the user, which will be quite difficult (although technically possible).